# How to arrange div elements without changing their order in html code?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="left"> DIV1 </div>

    <div class="right"> DIV2 </div>

    <div class="right"> DIV3 </div>

    <div class="right"> DIV4 </div>

    <div class="left"> DIV5 </div>

    <div class="right"> DIV6 </div>
</div>
```

How to arrange div elements as shown on the image without changing their order in html code?

[image]

Comment: Be careful with this. "When the source order matches the visual order, everyone will read the content and interact with it in the same (correct) order." See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C27.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use simple CSS for this to manipulate the position of the div. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7uwzccs1/

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="left1"> DIV1 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV2 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV3 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV4 </div>

<div class="left2"> DIV5 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV6 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left1{
   position: absolute;
}

.left2{
   position: absolute;
   left: 8px;
   top:  25px;
}

.right{ 
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with danielnixon that this isn't best practice and might be confusing if someone else will be editing your code at any point. I'd suggest to sort your HTML by the .left and .right classes to make it more intuitive:

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="left"> DIV1 </div>

<div class="left"> DIV5 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV2 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV3 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV4 </div>

<div class="right"> DIV6 </div>
```

I think the shortest route to what you want to achieve would be to float the divs with CSS like so:

```
.left {
float: left;
clear: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
clear: right;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xzgs61uw/2/

Additionally, if you want to move the divs closer together simply create .holder in your CSS and restrict its width, for example:

```
.holder {
width: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This of course also works leaving the original HTML structure in place.

Comment: Thank you for the you reply Krispy, but for some reasons the use of clear and float in my case is not suitable (http://jsfiddle.net/o8hpzhyz/). So I accepted the answer from NKD (http://jsfiddle.net/0oxdxx2c/)

Answer (score 0):

Use clear and float properties in CSS for each class. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkbjmgmt/)

```
.left{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.right{
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```